# What is the purpose of the quotes around some dollar values on certain retail sites?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, web

In doing some work on a project I stumbled across a formatting situation on a couple of websites that I couldn't explain.

When viewing the markup in the Google Chrome DOM inspector, some values appear with quotes around them. These quotes do not appear in either the HTML source nor the rendered page.

The format is as follows:

```
<span class="...">$</span>
"XX."
<span class="...">xx</span>
```

OR

```
"$XX."
<span class="...">xx</span>
```

OR some slight variation of the two. The large X's are the dollar amount in the price and the small x's are the cents.

The part of these structures I don't understand is the quotes around the dollar value.  Why are they used and why do they not appear in the display of the website?

Comment: A couple of websites to reference are: qvc.com, gifts.com, newegg.com

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Do they show up in the source or in some DOM inspector?

Comment: link to a specific example? I can't find any on newegg.com.

Comment: Do the quotes appear in "view source" or in the DOM? If there are quotes in the *source* I would expect them to show up on the page.

Comment: @Dave and pimvdb you were correct.  When I accessed the source the quotes were not present.  I had been using chrome's DOM inspector.  Why do they appear in the DOM inspector?

Comment: That was the info we missed: You see these quotes in Chrome's DOM Inspector. I updated your question tags to include `google-chrome` and provided an answer why Chrome's DOM Inspector uses these quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an "issue" with the Google Chrome DOM Inspector. When a String literal is not on the same line with its surrounding tag then the string literal is displayed on a new line with quotes around the string literal to make it visible where the string starts and ends.

For example when the string literal starts with a whitespace and is displayed in a new line inside the inspector then you only can see that if the string is quoted. Otherwise you won't be able to see where the string begins.

Inspect this with Google Chrome DOM Inspector:
http://jsfiddle.net/bFcNn/2/

These quotes exist neither in source code nor in the DOM after page has been loaded. They only exist as a structural element inside Google Chrome's DOM Inspector. They are at no time part of the page you're inspecting.

Comment: Damn, I missed the point making a screenshot of 1337 reputation score. Please undo two upvotes... :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is merely for formatting purposes so a different style can be applied to the `$` symbol, the dollars amount and the cents amount - example from View Source on a [product](http://www.qvc.com/qic/qvcapp.aspx/view.2/app.detail/params.CM_SCID.coll.item.A322200.desc.Softspots-Hugh-Huaraches) page on qvc.com:

```
<li class="introprice"><span class="intropricestyle">$</span>69.<span class="intropricestyle">00</span></li>
```

Comment: "The part of these structures I don't understand is the quotes around the dollar value."

Comment: That explains the reason for the spans, but I think the question was why the dollar amount is enclosed in quotes but it doesn't display on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess it's for screen readers.

I've noticed those sites seem to display dollars in a larger font, and the cents in a smaller font for effect, which a screen reader would not read correctly.

They mostly likely have the full amount in quotes in a span, and use CSS to hide that span.  That way, when a screen reader has focus on that control, the price will be read in its entirety.  As for the quotes, maybe they just felt like it or perhaps certain screen readers will behave differently with numeric values in quotes.

Perhaps you can post a URL to one of these so we can verify, but that's my hunch.