# Automatically line break in Yii

Tags: php, yii, whitespace

If not including PHP, there is no error.

If include Yii CMenu, automatically added white space before CMenu

Example:

```
<div id="umenu">
                    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
                        'encodeLabel' => false,
                        'items' => array(
                            array('label' => '&nbsp;', 'url' => '/', 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu1')),
                            array('label' => 'RÓLUNK', 'url' => StaticpageModule::getUrl(1), 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu2')),
                            array('label' => 'TERMELÉS', 'url' => StaticpageModule::getUrl(2), 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu3')),
                            array('label' => 'A KÁVÉ', 'url' => StaticpageModule::getUrl(3), 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu4')),
                            array('label' => 'EGYÜTTMŰKÖDÉS', 'url' => StaticpageModule::getUrl(5), 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu5')),
                            array('label' => 'KAPCSOLAT', 'url' => StaticpageModule::getUrl(4), 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu6')),
                        ),
                    )); ?>
                </div>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: It does not add it, you added it after opening `div#menu` and before `<?php`. It does not matter in page rendering.

Comment: array('label' => '&nbsp;', 'url' => '/', 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu1')), (&nbsp; is a white space at the first menu item) do you mean that?

Comment: i know, what is &nbsp;
I linked a picture, from output

Comment: It looks like "$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu... is outputting two quotes to the page before the table is drawn.  Is that really happening or just an artifact of the element inspector?  What does it look like when you view-source?

Comment: This solved my problem:

`
ob_start('My_OB');
function My_OB($str, $flags) {
    //remove UTF-8 BOM
    $str = preg_replace("/\xef\xbb\xbf/", "", $str);

    return $str;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Well, as *PeterM* said in its comment, you have whitespaces after opening `div#menu`...

And about double quotes you see in chrome dev tool :

> when a string literal is not on the same line with its surrounding tag
>   then the string literal is displayed on a new line with quotes around
>   the string literal to make it visible where the string starts and
>   ends.

[What is the purpose of the quotes around some dollar values on certain retail sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247011/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-quotes-around-some-dollar-values-on-certain-retail-si)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div id="umenu">
                <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
```

To

```
<div id="umenu"><?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the reference documentation for the widget constructor](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#widget-detail), it looks like you might need to pass false as the *$captureOutput* flag to tell it not to push any output to the page.

Try:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
                    'encodeLabel' => false,
                    'items' => array(
                        array('label' => '&nbsp;', 'url' => '/', 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu1')),
                        array('label' => 'RÓLUNK', 'url' => StaticpageModule::getUrl(1), 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu2')),
                        array('label' => 'TERMELÉS', 'url' => StaticpageModule::getUrl(2), 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu3')),
                        array('label' => 'A KÁVÉ', 'url' => StaticpageModule::getUrl(3), 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu4')),
                        array('label' => 'EGYÜTTMŰKÖDÉS', 'url' => StaticpageModule::getUrl(5), 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu5')),
                        array('label' => 'KAPCSOLAT', 'url' => StaticpageModule::getUrl(4), 'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'umenu6')),
                    ),
                    false
                ));
```

Comment: Ehh, never mind.  The default is already false.  I'd be curious whether 'true' changed the result at all though.